# Is it possible to read values from a running Mono executable assembly in a managed way?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I know I could probably do this by reading the process's memory but I would much rather do it in a managed way. Is it possible to somehow, without having control over the target assembly's source code, read the values of some variables?

Comment: That depends - for example you could "disassemble" the assembly and inject some code of your own...

Comment: Are you mentioning emitting? As far as I know, it's not available in Mono.

Comment: @Dmintry Nrkevich: what are you going actually to read, for instance?

Comment: I was hoping to read some values from a Unity game.

Comment: You probably can check out Mono Soft-Mode Debugger, http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:SoftDebugger

Comment: doesn't that require the target assembly to be built with the /debug flag though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Reflection to inspect metadata as well as memory/variables used by those classes.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't exist a Managed way of doing it. Won't this also contradict with the objective of OOPS?

Having a managed way of doing it would mean rendering Access Specifiers Invalid.